# VRML 2 export not visible

Tags: export

I am using Blender 2.7.8 on MacOS 10.12.3.

According to the [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/VRML2) blender can export VRML2. And that's what I want to do.

I created an empty Blender file, imported an STL, applied a material and searched for the VRML2 entry in the "File -> Export" menu:
[image]

As you can see it's not there. But the (as far as I understand) responsible scripts are existing (location: /Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.78/scripts/addons/io_scene_vrml2).

Can you please tell me why the export vrml option is missing?

Comment: Activate it in the user preferences (addon tab, then look at 'import export' category : it is near the end of the list)

Answer (score 3):

Go in user preference and under add-on tab search and activate the  add-on VRML2Export

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to export `.obj` to `.wrl` in Blender 2.8. The only option in Blender is to export the `.obj` to `.x3d` and then use a script to convert the `.x3d` to `.wrl`. Though there is another way - not using Blender for that task. Instead you can use [view3dscene](https://castle-engine.io/view3dscene.php). It is a viewer for many 3D models and it works like a charm!

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install view3dscene
view3dscene --write your_model.obj > your_model.wrl
```