# Issue with exporting Blender 4.0 file with texture for printing on J750

Tags: export

I am in desperate need of help for exporting my Blender file.
I have a design with texture, which I'm trying to export so that I can print it using Stratasys J750.
Ideally, I should be exporting it to a VRML file but that no longer seems to be an option for Blender 4.0.
Are there any suggestions on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: See [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)!

Comment: It's pretty old now, but it might be worth reading https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74060/vrml-2-export-not-visible